# Permutation problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

2 spaniels, 2 retrievers and 3 poodles go through to the final.  They are placed in line. How many different arrangements of these 7 dogs are there if no poodle is next to another poodle.

My attempt, spaniels and retrievers are 4!. Then ? I'm stuck here.

Comment: Arrange the spaniels and retrievers.  Now, make a bit of extra space inbetween each spaniel and retriever, enough space for at most one poodle to fit inbetween.  Choose *which* of the available spaces (including the outside) get used by poodles, and then pick which poodle specifically goes to which of said chosen spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down four stars like this:
$$\ast\qquad\ast\qquad\ast\qquad\ast$$
These represent the positions to be ultimately occupied by the non-poodles.

There are $5$ gaps, the $3$ obvious ones and the $2$ endgaps. We must choose $3$ of these to be occupied by the poodles. This can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways. The individual poodles can be put in the chosen gaps in $3!$ orders, and the rest of the dogs can occupy the starred positions in $4!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{5}{3}3!4!$.